# Retina Images on a non-retina display

Tags: macos, cocoa, retina-display

I'm experiencing a really strange behaviour on my OS X application. 
It seems that it is loading retina images even on a non-retina display. If I remove the @2x versions, the right @1x version is loaded.

I've already got this question [Retina version of an image always used on non-retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660082/retina-version-of-an-image-always-used-on-non-retina-display) but it is not related with my problem.

To export the images from my PSD I use Slicy (http://macrabbit.com/slicy/)

Do you have an idea of what can generate this behaviour?!

Comment: You don't have `@1x` in the name, right?

Comment: no :) I did't add any @1x