# Are specific PNG compression types incompatible with macOS Cocoa apps?

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-sierra

We’ve had a recent issue with some asset images, where the Retina `@2x` version was being used on non-Retina devices. The Retina and non-Retina versions of the assets exist. We’ve tracked the problem down to compression, so we’re able avoid it for now, but if anyone has additional insights, I’d love to hear them.

The icons on the left show how they’re rendering inside the running app. The Retina assets are being used on a non-Retina screen, so they’re being scaled down to 50%, which is causing some blurry edges.

The icons on the right are the original assets.

[image: PNG compression causing non-Retina issues]

This is only happening to some assets. Most of the app is okay. We’ve been using [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com) to compress the PNGs used in the app. ImageOptim is using a variety of compression combinations for the assets. These are the common best results:

- `PNGOUT`
- `PNGOUT+AdvPNG`
- `PNGOUT+Zopfli`
- `AdvPNG+Zopfli`

The assets that have problems all seem to be using `PNGOUT+Zopfli`, but not all assets with `PNGOUT+Zopfli` are bad. I am not 100% confident with this diagnosis though.

Given that the issue isn’t always easy to spot, and given I don’t know exactly what’s wrong, we’ve unfortunately decided to not compress our new PNGs used in Mac apps. This is a shame, because the space savings are good.

We’ve tried a few different Xcode project settings, including turning `Combine High Resolution Artwork` on and off.

[image: Combine High Resolution Artwork in Xcode]

I’d like some answers, but I am also posting here so there’s some information that may help others with this issue, even if I only have a partial solution.

---

### Have you seen this issue before?

### If you have seen it, do you have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `NSImage` representations are chosen using color type and resolution [[1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/1520010-preferscolormatch)]. In case of PNG files, there are situations when a more generic color type gives a smaller file. This is what causes the mixed color types between representations.

You need to set `prefersColorMatch` to `NO`. There are *User Defined Runtime Attributes* to do it without leaving Interface Builder. This will fix the issue.

[How to set prefersColorMatch in Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tdxk.png)

Comment: Great solution, thanks. I’m happy this info is now here so others can find it. :)

Answer (score 1):

More information about the bug can be found here:

> OS X doesn't like mixed types of PNGs.

[Retina version of an image always used on non-retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660082/retina-version-of-an-image-always-used-on-non-retina-display)

It looks like there is no solution, except to force the same `color_type` for the PNG pairs.

Comment: Hi Marc - why would your color types be mismatched for the above images? Is the ImageOptim pass somehow finding a smaller result for you with different color types? Is there a way to restrict the color types scanned during the ImageOptim pass?

Comment: @fbrereto I think ImageOptim just treats each source image separately, and runs it through all the various processing combinations to find the smallest lossless result. Occasionally a 1× image and 2× image end up with mismatched color type. I don’t think there’s a way to restrict color types, but Kornel (ImageOptim’s dev) is aware and working on some solutions.